# Measure data transfers in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Google used to have an extension called [Data Saver](https://m.wikihow.com/Use-Google%27s-Data-Saver-Extension-to-Check-Data-Usage-in-Chrome) that would provide good metrics on data transfers; that tool is no longer available (recently pulled from the Web Store).  Other than going to the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools and viewing the single statistic for "Transferred" is there a better way to monitor data transfers into a web application?  Thx!